# Low Memory Machine Completes Large Table Alters In Much Less Time

Tags: mysql, buffer, percona

I have two database servers.

Server A has 128GB memory with 75% for buffer_pool
Server B has 64GB memory with 25% for buffer_pool

There is no activity on Server A but an ALTER on a 220 GB table.
There is replication activity on Server B on ALTER on same 220 GB table.

Server B completes in half the time.

Can someone explain what might cause this behavior? All settings across Server A and B are similar except for memory and buffer_pool alotments.

Both are identical OS and Server A has 16 core CPU, while Server B has 8 core.

Comment: Need much more information here like graphs of disk IO on both machines, CPU/memory usage, etc. Both tables are same engine?

Answer (score 0):

Not everything is main memory, in my case, factors like OS and CPU make a big difference. I tested same DB in different machines (for a project I worked on), and found a better general performance in a Linux i5-6200U and 8gb DDR4 machine than a W7 i7-4000 and 16gb DDR3 (around a 20% better performance)

Comment: Updated my question with OS and CPU specs